# Comparing Factor Structures Between Groups/Difference in Sample Size?

Tags: sample-size, factor-analysis

I am comparing the factor structure of an autism screener across two groups (group 1->  toddlers diagnosed with Down syndrome; group 2-> toddlers diagnosed with Cerebral Palsy). The first group has a sample size of 186 and the second group has a sample size of 395. Will this difference in sample size create difficulties when comparing the EFAs?

Comment: It might, but it's very difficult to say from the outside, it depends on many things. How many indicators do you have and do you have a theoretically based idea about the factor structure? However, maybe more importantly, it might be better to use multi-group confirmatory factor analysis instead of separate EFAs for factor structure comparisons between groups.